# Do De Morgan's laws require complementation in a common superset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The De Morgan laws are often stated as:

> Let $A, B\subset X$. Then we have
> \begin{align}
> X\setminus (A\cup B) &= (X\setminus A)\cap(X\setminus B), \quad\text{and}\\
> X\setminus(A\cap B) &= (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B).
> \end{align}

But I am able to prove them, quite easily, without the requirement that $A, B$ be subsets of $X$. So why is it always mentioned while stating the above?

Comment: The usual formulation of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is in terms of complements, where $A,B$ are subsets of a common superset $X$ against which the complements are defined. The way the identities are written here is sometimes called [relative complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) and in that case there is no requirement for $X$ to be a superset.

Comment: These deMorgan's laws do not *require* $A,B\subset X$, it is just somewhat *useful* to know that that is sufficient for them to hold.  "For any two sets, $A$, $B$ in our universe $X$, ..."

Comment: There is no such thing as a superset or universe in ZF set theory.